# Interact with .OBJ?

Tags: aframe

Is it possible to interact with .OBJ models?
 I'm trying to animate the rotation of my imported .obj model, and incorporate the cursor for "clicking" on the model triggering an animation. I would appreciate some information on how to do this.

I would also like to know if it is possible to use the mouse on the destop to rotate the .OBJ model instead of moving the camera.

Here is my code so far:

```
<a-scene class="surgical" inspector="url: https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe-inspector.min.js" embedded>
<a-assets>
<a-asset-item id="trapezium-model" src="trapezium.obj"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
<a-sky src="textures/surgical360.jpg"></a-sky>
<a-obj-model src="#trapezium-model" position="-31.81 6.72 -89.53" material="metalness:0.38;roughness:0.3;flatShading:false"></a-obj-model>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To animate a property of an object, you can use the [`a-animation`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/core/animations.html) elements:

```
<a-obj-model src="#trapezium-model"
             position="-31.81 6.72 -89.53"
             material="metalness:0.38;
                       roughness:0.3;
                       flatShading:false">
  <a-animation attribute="rotation"
           dur="10000"
           fill="forwards"
           to="0 360 0"
           repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
</a-obj-model>
```

For using the mouse to rotate, [aframe-orbit-controls](https://github.com/subsumo/aframe-orbit-controls) is a wrapper around THREE.OrbitControls. That's definitely the place to start. It may be a little tricky to switch between animated rotation and mouse rotation on the same object.